# How to get certification in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, certification

I want to get certified in Magento. My question is that whether it would be beneficial to get certified now or it would be better to wait for the time when Magento 2 certification will be available.

Please guide me, because I want to get it for a better career path.

If it is better to prepare for Magento 2.x certification, please share some good resources from where I can start preparation.

**Note:** I know links for Magento 1.x certification.

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento 1 support ends in June 2020, that mean magento2 is future.

But that doesn't mean you will not get work for M1.

there are thousands of store still and will be running on M1,

in that case, if you have certification for M1 then you will have a better chance for that project.

for me Let time to come and once they release certification for M2 Then do M2 certificate as well

until that time you have your M1 certificate to show your talent.

And in future for a project like migration If you have M1 and M2 both certificates, you will have a better chance for that project.

So for me doing certification Right now also has some advantage so go and earn that certificate.

> **Update**

Magento 2 developer certificate is here : https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.Wp44zObhVNB

you can even try to give magento 2 certification

Also there is another new exam for beginners : [Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam)

Comment: Just so you know M1 EOL has been postponed ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism they release new date for m1 EOL ? or still not fixed ??

Comment: https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support

Comment: Just quick question after m1 date has been postponed , for new projects which Magento version we use ? Magento1 or Magento 2 ? @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: @KeyurShah I personally prefer M2 for new projects, bcuz M1 at any M1 support will be closed

Comment: Yes, even I think so, but after postponed date I am not sure , thanks for the comments. Also, I started conversion here https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/thought-for-magento-1-ongoing-support

Comment: You can add your valuable thoughts there @MurtuzaZabuawala